# When introducing the Optimizer variables under variable_scope get recreated twice, why?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, tensorboard

As the title suggests, when looking at the graph inside tensorboard - the variables I've created inside a variable_scope get recreated twice.  Why is that? what am I doing wrong?

```
def weights_biases(weights_shape, biases_shape):
    weights = tf.get_variable("weights", weights_shape, initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer())
    biases = tf.get_variable("biases", biases_shape, initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer())

    return weights, biases

def hl_relu(input_tensor, weights_shape, biases_shape):
    weights, biases = weights_biases(weights_shape, biases_shape)
    regression = tf.matmul(input_tensor, weights) + biases
    return tf.nn.relu(regression)

def neural_network_model(x):
    # W = tf.Variable(
    #    tf.truncated_normal([vocab_size, embedding_size], stddev=1 / math.sqrt(vocab_size)),
    #    name="W")

    # embedded = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, x)    
    # embedding_aggregated = tf.reduce_sum(embedded, [1])

    with tf.variable_scope("hidden_layer_1"):
        relu1 = hl_relu(x, [max_words_len, n_nodes_hl1], [n_nodes_hl1])

    with tf.variable_scope("hidden_layer_2"):
        relu2 = hl_relu(relu1, [n_nodes_hl1,n_nodes_hl2], [n_nodes_hl2])

    with tf.variable_scope("hidden_layer_3"):
        relu3 = hl_relu(relu2, [n_nodes_hl2,n_nodes_hl3], [n_nodes_hl3])

    with tf.variable_scope("output_layer"):
        weights, biases = weights_biases([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes], [n_classes])
        output_regression = tf.matmul(relu3, weights) + biases

    return output_regression

def train_neural_network(test_x, test_y):
    with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
        custom_runner = CustomRunner()
        x_batch, y_batch = custom_runner.get_inputs()

        with tf.variable_scope("test"):
            testX = tf.constant(test_x, name="testX")
            testX = tf.cast(testX, tf.float32)
            testY = tf.constant(test_y, name="testY")
            testY = tf.cast(testY, tf.float32)

        with tf.variable_scope("nn") as scope:
            global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='global_step')    

            logits = neural_network_model(x_batch)
            scope.reuse_variables()
            test_logits = neural_network_model(testX)

            cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, y_batch), name="cost")
            tf.scalar_summary('cost', cost)
            optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost, global_step = global_step)
```

Produces the following abnormality:

[image: DNN Graph]

You can see that the 'nn' scope was created twice with my hidden layers which are not connected to any inputs, but affect the Adagrad optimizer by providing their initialized random weight constantly.  I suspect this is also slowing down training.

What have i done wrong in my code??

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what is causing them to be created twice.

```
logits = neural_network_model(x_batch)
scope.reuse_variables()
test_logits = neural_network_model(testX)
```

Can you change that to this:

```
logits = neural_network_model(x_batch)
```

without the test_logits and see if you still get the same issue?

Comment: Unfortunately they do.  Those lines do seem out of context, my apologies for that, thats because further down the method (that I didn't copy) there's an accuracy calculation and such.  But anyways, even if I remark these two lines you mentioned this problem still occurs.  I am completely lost as to why this happens.... it's only when I use scopes tho.  Without scopes it wouldn't happen.  The problem is, that I must use scopes if I want to use the QueueRunner feed... that's also why i have the above two lines.

Comment: Also note that adam and adadelta do create an extra set of variables for themselves.  If you look at the model files that get created you'd notice that they are twice as big while using those methods.  They need to do this because that's the way their methods work.

Comment: I'll totally buy that, it's just that when I don't use scopes i don't see those extra variables that i've referenced in the screenshot above.  I only see the extra ones prefixed with update_.  Those are not the ones above.

Comment: So tensorboard organizes the graph differently depending on scoping (it isn't really clear to me how, usually tries to put the scopes in boxes within the other scopes).  It could just be on the side when you don't use variable scopes.  Also when you don't use naming tensorflow will still create those variables but use the previous scope instead.

Comment: Exactly.  And I use scoping because instead of feeding my data through placeholders directly from memory, I have tried feeding the data through OPs that read the data from tfrecord example proto(s).  The whole thing is excessively slow, and I mean orders of magnitude slower and also seems to barely get better with time in terms of cost and accuracy.  That in turn prompted me to look closer at the graph and i've noticed that utilizing these scopes which is the only thing that allowed me to feed my test batches, created an extra set of hidden layer variables which are initialized...

Comment: ... but don't get fed any inputs.  Tho their outputs are being considered and changed by the Adagrad optimizer.  But sure, let's say that this is all fine and by design... is there anything in the code above that seems like it would make everything run so slow or for the model to not train properly?

Comment: There would be a couple of things to check for. 1) make sure you aren't recreating tf.Variables 2) your custom runner, 3) gpu >> cpu (usually but not always) 4) check the timing of just the cost step versus other parts.  Otherwise there isn't really anything wrong with your code I'd say.

Comment: 4) is what I should have addressed before.  It seems that if I just calculate cost but comment out the accuracy part and skip feeding it the test data, it runs faster.  Still comparatively slower than when using placeholders.

Comment: so actually there's a blog post on this, tf placeholders are in general at the moment faster than using queues. Here's the blog post  https://indico.io/blog/tensorflow-data-inputs-part1-placeholders-protobufs-queues/ you have to work at it to get it to be faster than or as fast as placeholders.

Comment: This blog post is why I'm confused and started looking at the graph more closely. You'll notice that in the beginning of train_neural_network() I use that same CustomRunner class they point to in part 2 of that linked blog article.  And I preload everything into memory.  And still I don't see an improvement not to mention that my model doesn't train as well as it would if it was purely from memory, fed with placeholders directly via feed_dict.  Thats what prompted taking a closer look at the graph and finding this extra NN layer hidden inside the NN scope. Problem is feed_dict doesn't scale.

Comment: One more thing worth mentioning is that I don't see any open issue about this apparently known problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the variables are re-created? I suspect what you see is just Adagrad variables created by the optimizer so that is can save what it needs for its computation. Can you try the simplest GradientDescentOptimizer and see if it still happens?

Comment: You're right that with the GradientDescentOptimizer I don't see the same thing happening.  However, with the AdamOptimizer and the AdagradOptimizer I definitely see more than just the update variables.  You can even see in the example picture above that I get a new scope with the same name, that has its own weights and biases and NO inputs only outputs which ultimately affect the optimizer.  That's in ADDITION to the other layers outputting to the optimizer.  So I basically have double the outputs for every layer going into the optimizer. (excuse the caps, just wanted to highlight)

Comment: I don't know how to post any more images, but i'd gladly do so.

Comment: The whole thing started because I compared utilizing a QueueRunner and feeding the data with placeholders and my model crawled, very noticeably.  And then I started looking into the graph and found this... I'm suspecting it has something to do with my model crawling and also having some suspicious results.

Comment: Have you tried finalizing the graph before your first session.run